# Is there a way to trigger immediate invalidation of a PHP file system cache if MYSQL data changes?

Tags: php, mysql, caching, invalidation

I have a simple site on a shared hosting service and I use basic PHP output caching (writing HTML output to files). The data of the site does not change often, but when it does then only I make changes, so the site has no update interface, because it does not need one, I simply log in to the phpmyadmin interface and upload the modifications as SQL statements.

This works well, the only problem is the changes do not appear immediately on the site, only when the cache time expires. Is there some way to trigger cache invalidation from mysql, so the caches are cleared when I change data in the database. For example, I could add one more sql line to the update which would somwehow call an external program in the home directory if it's possible, but is it?

If it's not then is there some clever way for MYSQL to notify the PHP side about a data update without PHP having to connect to the database (if there is a cached version of the page then it uses that and does not connect to the database, because that is the point).

Comment: Do you have access to cron (or other means of configuring repeated tasks) in your hosting service?

Comment: Yes, cron is available, but the minimum repeat interval allowed is 30 minutes, so it's not really useful for quick cache invalidation. Of course, I could try to start 30 cron jobs with different start times to achieve 1 minute granularity, but it's a clumsy solution.

Comment: You may implement your own simplified cron (that is, a php script that will check DB for updates regularly), and run it once.

Comment: I had a very similar problem recently, so I thought I could as well publish the solution. https://github.com/chibisuke/mysql_exec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there some clever way for MYSQL to notify the PHP side about a data update without PHP having to connect to the database

There is not, and you should not want this.

You may write a special PHP script on your site which will invalidate the cache, and call it manually each time you update the DB. Or you may store your cache in DB (rather than in files).

Comment: Yes, but it's an extra manual step. I can do that, but I asked the question first if there is a better way. Storing the cache in DB kind of defeats the point, because I cache to avoid unnecessary DB calls.

Comment: In db-to-php interaction, db is a server, and db is a client. The connection between server and client should be established by client. Also, usually on a shared hosting DB service is running on server different from one your PHP scripts are working, and there is no corresponding user (and, as a consequence, your "home directory") on a DB server for the reasons of security.

Comment: I'm sure you have a section in your php code. if Cache is null then create my Cache Object. you can extend with a additional parameter if ResetCache is true then drop the my current cache object and create a new Cache object..but this is quick and dirty way...the additional step in a secure area on your webapp is a better way.

Comment: There's no way you can run shell command from phpMyAdmin that I know of (especially in shared hosting). If you don't want to connect to your database to check if cache needs to be invalidated then you'll have to go with penartur's suggestion aby manually calling special script or get your hands dirty with cron.

Comment: Probably a good php mvc framework have a RowVersion or TimeStamp check for the model (like a concurrency check). With this Model State you can set or reset your cache object in your php application.

Comment: But any rowversion or timestamp check neeeds db connection, doesn't it? So it kind of defeats the point of not connecting to the db.

Comment: After all, i doubt there is a point in such optimizations (like reducing the number of connections to DB) on a shared hosting. If the shared hosting performance is not enough, I'd just opted in for a more expensive plan; savings on a hosting are probably much less significant than costs of such "_optimizations_" (both in terms of time spent optimizing it now, and time spent in the future trying to fix such "optimization"). And if one is already using dedicated server, then there are more maintanable ways to do optimizations.

Comment: But trying to do such tricky optimizations on a shared hosting is certainly not worth it. BTW, even with the small wages in the country I live in, the price of a dedicated server per month is about what i'm getting for 5 hours of work. The time @Tom spent asking this question on stackoverflow is probably already cost him as much as the upgrade to faster hosting would.

Comment: Yes, I could go for a dedicated server, but I like the managed service, I don't want to administer my own server and a managed dedicated server is more expensive than an unmanaged one. But I don't really need the extra power the question was mainly about finding out if there is a way to send a notification from MYSQL to PHP, so I was just curious.

Comment: The plain logic answers that there is no such a way at least due to security reasons (MySQL is usually hosted on an entirely different server, and doing any sort of external communication in MySQL, even if there is some, is likely to be forbidden by your hoster). Anyway, sending events from DB to PHP is a bad idea. Run a service on your PHP server which will check regularly for the DB validity. Or you may trigger the check on some conditions from the PHP scripts that serve your client (e.g. store the last check time in a file, and if it was more than a minute ago, perform the actual check).